# Protobuf: Cannot open include file common.h in message.pb.h file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile this project: https://github.com/shaochuan/cmake-protobuf-example. I successfully compiled protobuf with msvc2015 (x64). The check project runs without errors (All result: PASSED).

I set up the project in cmake, provided all the paths:

`Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/TK/protobuf-330/msvc2015_64/install/include`
    `Protobuf_LIBRARY_DEBUG=C:/TK/protobuf-330/msvc2015_64/install/lib/libprotobufd.lib`
          `Protobuf_LITE_LIBRARY_DEBUG=C:/TK/protobuf-330/msvc2015_64/install/lib/libprotobuf-lited.lib`

`Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE=C:/TK/protobuf-330/msvc2015_64/install/bin/protoc.exe`
`Protobuf_PROTOC_LIBRARY_DEBUG=C:/TK/protobuf-330/msvc2015_64/install/lib/libprotocd.lib`
`Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER=C:\TK\src\protobuf-330\src`

The proto-project compiles without any error. It includes the `message.cc` and `message.h` files. The CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER message.proto)
ADD_LIBRARY(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})
```

If I compile the main project with the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(rpc)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.6)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(proto)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

and then build it, I receive this error (C1083) saying:

> "Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h': No such file or directory"   c:\tktest\protobuftest\src\proto\message.pb.h

In the file the erroneous line is:

```
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
```

I cannot figure out what went wrong.Any hints are appreciated. Are there some known problems regarding cmake + protobuf + visual studio 2015?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to Macxx and utopia. I added both of the suggested lines to the end of the proto-project CMakeLists.txt and change the project properties of both projects to "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)". And now it works. Still could figure out what the problem was. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CMakeLists.txt you should replace `PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR` with `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR` or `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS` (note the `S` at the end) and `PROTOBUF_LIBRARY` with `Protobuf_LIBRARY` or `Protobuf_LIBRARIES`. CMake variable names are case sensitive. I just checked with the CMake 3.9 version. The FindProtobuf.cmake module which is implicitely called when using find_package(Protobuf) defines those variables when run successful.

Comment: Great point. This is also why I use lowercase by default everywhere except in non-local variables. Uppercase everywhere also makes it harder to read.

Comment: Also relevant for Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take an educated guess here since I don't know anything about protobuf.

Prefer the `target_*` commands.

proto-project CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_include_directories(proto
  PUBLIC
    "${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

That says, everything that uses the `proto` target will be able to access any includes in "${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}" as well as `proto` itself also able to access them.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. It seems that the main-project CMakeLists.txt does not set the ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY} variable.

Comment: I added your suggestion as well as the line provided by Macxx. Know it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On my PC the project is compiling, but not linking. So, to fix this issue the library *proto* needs to link the protobuf library. This can be done by adding the following line to `proto/CMakeLists.txt`

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

After this change it works on my PC.

Comment: I added your suggestion as well as the line provided by utopia. Thanks